# Prevent lines from appearing twice in the legend

Tags: r, plot, legend

I have asked a question about this legend a hour or so ago [Align symbols in the legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023690/align-symbols-in-the-legend), but now a new issue has emerged. I would like to add lines to my legend. I ried the following:

```
plot(1:4)
legend("topleft",legend=expression(theta[1]==7%*%10^-4,theta[1]==0,
                                   theta[2]==-14%*%10^-4,theta[2]==0),
       lty=c(2,1),lwd=2,col=c("blue","grey"),bty="n",cex=1.2,ncol=2)
```

[image]

But the lines should only appear once per line: one blue line in the first line and one grey line in the second line. I then tried inserting zeros, so `lty=c(2,1,0,0)`, but there appears space between the thetas.

It should look like this:

[image]

Has anyone a suggestion how I can prevent the lines from appearing twice in my legend?

Comment: you are passing four objects in expression, so legend thinks you want four different lines. How do you want the expressions to appear?

Comment: As they would appear with `lty=c(2,1,0,0)`, but without space between the thetas.

Comment: So the lines would appear only once in the first column...

Comment: oh, you could just change col to `col=c("blue", NA, "grey", NA)` then. and also `lyt = c(2,2,1,1)`

Comment: -1 you did not even try the solution I gave you in the first question

Comment: @baptiste Now I have! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually the lines are only appearing 4 times because you have created a 4 element expression vector. (The lines argument is being recycled.) This solution "protects" the interior commas from interpretation, althoug looking at it again I see that the order was not what you indended. You should be able to fix than now that I have demonstrated how to better incorporate commas in expressions:

```
plot(1:4)
legend("topleft",legend=expression(theta[1]==7%*%10^-4*","~theta[1]==0,
                                   theta[2]==-14%*%10^-4*","~theta[2]==0),
       lty=c(2,1),lwd=2,col=c("blue","grey"),bty="n",cex=1.2,ncol=2)
```

You may need to adjust the location since it impinges on the  fourth point, but then again this is clearly not your use case. Consider using ncol=1.

[image]

Response to edit: So you didn't want the commas but only spaces. The add more tildes:

```
png(); plot(1:4)
legend("topleft",legend=expression(theta[1]==7%*%10^-4~theta[2]==-14,
                                   theta[1]==0 ~~~~~~~~~~~~theta[2]==0),
 ncol=1, lty=c(2,1),lwd=2,col=c("blue","grey"),bty="n",cex=1.2);dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: I added a plot how it should look like, without commas but with small distances. As one can see, my second plot is not perfect, because the thetas in the second column are not exactly in the same over each other.

Comment: Unfortunately it is also not a perfect solution, because the thetas are not aligned well. I need it correctly, because it is for my scientific work...

Comment: Your "scientific work"? What does that mean? Since when does the exact alignment of annotations represent good science? The `legend` function does not have a tab locator. If you need to locate the second parameter sub-expression with such precision, then use the `text` function. Hack the legend function if you demand perfection.

Comment: My masters thesis. Exact alignment of annotations does not represent good science, but the plots in the work should look appropriate and not with messy symbols.